# Trouble with content security policy

Tags: html, content-security-policy, meta

So i have been trying to use a google programmable search engine script, but i am having trouble with the meta tag.
The meta tag that i have included in my  is as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src *.google.com 'self';">
```

However, i am still getting an error telling me it refused to load the script because it violates the "content-security-policy directive: "script-src 'self'""

I am wondering whether it inherits some sort of settings from somewhere else, as it doesn't accept the new script-src i am setting, however it does accept the new script-src if i set it to 'none'.

By the way, I am very new to html, so i might be making some obvious mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 Content-Security-Policy issued. If multiple CSPs the strictest rules from both will apply (all sources/tokens should pass via both CSPs unscratched).

Content Security Policy could be delivered 2 ways:

- via HTTP header `Content-Security-Policy:` (prefereed)
- via meta-tag (restricted possibilities)

So you need to check for double `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` in the HTML code.

And check the HTTP response headers(because CMS could publush CSP by default) in the browser developers tool (Crtl+Shift+i in Chrome and Crtl+Shift+k in Fifrefox  -> Network tab -> select main page at the left window and look Response headers):
[image: response headers in the browser console]

Comment: Yes, it seems it is coming from the response header.
I have never worked with HTTP response headers or anything server related (which i assume this is?) - how would one go about changing this?

Comment: By default Web-server does not publish CSP headers, therefore search vectors:1. Headers plugin for CMS (most probability). 2. File .htaccess or nginx config, see https://csplite.com/csp31/  3. PHP-server: header() function in code. 4. Java-server: Headers() construct.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will give this a try when i have some more time, as this is completely new to me, so it will probably take me some time to understand fully.