# Refused to execute inline script for Redocly

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

Trying `redoc-cli` (https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/) to generate static documentation. No luck with these errors. It looks like `Content-Security-Policy` don't allow JS code at all.

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-g6NjhUYDGd6SXSIYkvuQkZhdbtqx8hqNKVM8JKvqpy4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

```
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
base-uri;
connect-src *;
default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com;
font-src * data:;
form-action;
img-src * data:;
manifest-src *;
media-src;
object-src *;
report-to;
script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
script-src-attr * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
script-src-elem * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
style-src * data: 'unsafe-inline';
style-src-attr * data: 'unsafe-inline';
style-src-elem * data: 'unsafe-inline';
">
```

**Update**

Finally fixed.

Server should send these headers:

"Content-Security-Policy" = "script-src blob:"
"Content-Security-Policy" = "worker-src blob:"

And HTML should have `manifest.json` with additional fields:

```
{
  "content_security_policy": "script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'",
  "csp": "script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error *Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: **"script-src 'self'**"*, the lock occurs in the `script-src 'self'`.
But your CSP in meta tag does not have this.

It means you actually have another CSP issued. Usually apps middleware have a default CSP issued via HTTP header, but technically you could have 2 meta-tags CSP too.
If there are 2 CSPs, the stricter one applies.

Check the HTML code for 2 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` and check in the Developer tools the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) is a tutorial).

After fix of above:

- report-to directive is not supported in meta tag, so you could remove it
- `'unsafe-eval'` token is not supported in the *script-src-attr*/*script-src-elem* directives. It is a page's global flag and could be used in *script-src*/*default-src* only (see [note](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-script-src) in para 4.).
- `*` and `data:` is not supported in the *style-src-attr* directive. It controls the `style='...'` attribute in the tags, and no any scheme-sources used there.
- `*` is not supported in the *script-src-attr* directive. It controls event handlers like `onClick='...'` or javascript-navigation like `<a href='javascript:...'` and no any scheme-sources used there except `javascript:`.

Full [check-list of errors](http://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJyVj81KBDEQhO%2BC7xByGRCyC%2F5Ccty7CD5Bb6YztuRnSPcsivjuxmFXx0VwvYSq9FedCtgr%2B8bt0IFetLt3bG%2BsjrjDqB3ZSzfPNo8Puqnru1urt8Bopkru%2FMyXnNGL4erVRfM9Bpji3qtuygwBDeVIGbsvjzuInepBwKoBRqueREa26zVzXA0sIORXvqS2MJR82Dbz81VNBrxQyc1RGo7mCTIF5O9SCXuCT9d02T4v%2B1YcSxUjpWn2lcaTqv%2BADYjU%2FyUwYjolIa8Rl587TiyZQ42%2Fwf3rv4PavX8ALz6sBA%3D%3D#result). But you could leave of above in the CSP, browser just ignores those.