# CSP for embedding youtube video

Tags: content-security-policy, youtube-iframe-api

I've just started seeing this with my embedded youtube videos on Chrome (86.0.4240.193 - recently updated which is probably why I'm just seeing this) - these are 'reports' only, so the videos still show but 100s of errors can't be right!  This is what I'm seeing:

```
[Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' https: 'report-sample' 'nonce-t9IE7nI2leo7qKxsm7d80g=='".
```

Here's my iFrame --

```
<iframe id="video-iframe" width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIDDENVIDEO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

I cannot figure out what the CSP should be -- here's one that I found that apparently solved their problem --

```
<iframe id="video-iframe" width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIDDENVIDEO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen csp="script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.youtube.com/ https://s.ytimg.com/; object-src 'self'; child-src https://www.youtube.com/* https://s.ytimg.com/"></iframe>
```

Not so much -- I just see: Refused to display....

Any help much appreciated.

I just checked the `developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples` page and I'm seeing the same thing -- surely this shouldn't be happening, right?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see, this error is triggered not your CPS - your's do not have `'nonce-t9IE7nI2leo7qKxsm7d80g=='"` token. This error appears within Google's `<iframe>` and it's totally Google's internal deal.

The fact is that several previous versions of Chrome had a bug and [did not block eval](https://csplite.com/csp/test282/) expressions.
In version 86 Chrome, they fixed this bug, and to verify this, they set the Report-Only header and made a fake call to eval to see reports.

[CSP for Youtube](https://csplite.com/csp/test40/) is very simple and does not require 'unsafe-eval', because all works within isolated iframe:
`frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com;` is enough to allow for Youtube in iframe.

---

By the way, your CSP has an [error](https://csplite.com/ru/csp/check/?pl=eJx1jc0KwjAQhF8l7KUgtMU%2FhN2jdxF8gjRu20hqSje1FvHdDTlZ0MswzDfMaNziS6JAbZ9AJxLcIzh%2BsAOyuKHEjpczRLc%2B7BDEDLYPuQxGZcKuzlQbQi9YltM0FY33jeNc37WbgzVSGN%2BVi8bsxzBWvARSxHbXpJCUr25svi9Imda6a0r%2Bba1%2BjgG9PyStTKs%3D#result) - the `*` is not allowed in path-part. And be careful with [<iframe csp=](https://csplite.com/csp153/#iframe_csp) - if server does not agree with your CSP, content will be blocked.
But this `<iframe csp=` played the role because of once more Chrome bug - it ignores Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only if Content-Security-Policy header presence.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - much appreciated.  I went through details at the link, so, I can simply ignore these - and no need to include a CSP, right?

Comment: Yes, you do not need any steps since it's not your CSP. Google is in charge for these, it will remove Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header after check up.

Comment: @granty A shame you linked to the solution instead of putting it in your Answer, as the link has apparently rotted away

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience caused. I added into answer CSP for youtube for any case. What else do you suggest adding to the answer?

Comment: I am sorry i tried the following: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com;">

and it still does give me the same following error: Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'none'".

Comment: Check do you have a CSP header published, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). If you have published CSP via HTTP header, the `<meta CSP>` can't relax it. In case of 2 CSPs at the same time and all sources should pass unscratched though both CSPs.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my embedded videos working using a `meta` tag in the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none'; frame-src youtube.com https://www.youtube.com;">
```

add the `https://` to `www.youtube.com`