# Codeigniter Content Security Policy

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-security-policy, codeigniter-4

Meddling with CSP for the first time. It's exhausting to be honest!

I've got the general gist of things, but I need a bit of guidance.

This is the default copied from the `ContentSecurityPolicy.php` in my `Config` folder:

```
    public $defaultSrc     = null; // will default to self if not over-ridden
    public $scriptSrc      = 'self';
    public $styleSrc       = 'self';
    public $imageSrc       = 'self';
    public $baseURI        = null;    // will default to self if not over-ridden
    public $childSrc       = 'self';
    public $connectSrc     = 'self';
    public $fontSrc        = null;
    public $formAction     = 'self';
    public $frameAncestors = null;
    public $mediaSrc       = null;
    public $objectSrc      = 'self';
    public $manifestSrc    = null;
```

This is from my `BaseController` which my `Controller` extends to:

```
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.:
        // $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        /* $this->response->CSP->setDefaultSrc('self'); */
        $this->response->CSP->setDefaultSrc('self');
        $this->response->CSP->addStyleSrc('https://fonts.googleapis.com');
        $this->response->CSP->addImageSrc(['http://cdn1.feelunique.com', 'http://feelunique.feedspark.com', 'http://s.cdnsbn.com', 'https://assets.feelunique.com', 'https://cdn1.feelunique.com', 'https://i.notino.com', 'https://images2.productserve.com', 'https://www.sobelia.com', ]);
```

Neither the font, nor the images.. or even images stored on my own web hosting are showing when I switch CSP to `true`.

Can anyone give me a bit of guidance what step I'm missing in the process, please?

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Showing the actual errors and all CSP response headers and meta tags (if any) would help in understanding your problem.

Comment: Check which CSP header you really have in browser, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). Anyway images stored on your own web hosting should be shown with your ContentSecurityPolicy.php default settings.