# Content Security Policy problems...iframes and inline styling

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-4, content-security-policy, inline-styles

I have a HTML/EJS webpage with the following Content Security Policy in the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; frame-src https://externalpage.com/">
```

As can be seen, I have stated a URL for the "frame-src" in order to load an external iframe into the page.  This, however, is not functional.  The error is the following:

"Refused to frame 'https://externalpage.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

The iframe is similar to the following:

```
<iframe width="256" height="256" style="display:inline-block;border:none;" src="//externalpage.com/ect/long/remainder/of/url/link/here</iframe>
```

The error message persists even if I remove the 'default-src' directive.  I have also tried to define a 'wildcard' as "https://externalpage.com/*" without success.  I also do not understand why the error indicates that I have not set a 'frame-src' directive, when I clearly have.  What am I to do to resolve this...????

In addition as can be seen I was forced to add an "unsafe-inline" rule in order to allow inline styling, such as "div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:30px""  ...is there some way to get around this?  I know the 'unsafe-inline' should not be used due to security issues.

This Content Security Policy nonsense is madness.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have 2 different CSPs - the first one via HTTP header, and the second - via meta tag.

Content Security Policy in the HTTP header has more strict rules, therefore it is who actually performs the locks.

Check is there CSP delivered in HTTP header ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) is tutorial).

> 

Multi-scheme URL like `<iframe src="//externalpage.com/">` means that on HTTP:-pages it will be `<iframe src="http://externalpage.com/">` and on HTTPS: - `<iframe src="https://externalpage.com/">` (browser add the scheme on its own using to Same Origin Policy).
Hence you need to use `frame-src externalpage.com` without scheme too.
On HTTP:-pages it will be `frame-src http://externalpage.com` and the `frame-src https://externalpage.com` on HTTPS: pages.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I find it informative.  I have retrieved the HTTP response header using the method you provided.  Where does this CSP originate from?  I am using my localhost, so I do not understand how this CSP is set?  Also, more importantly...how do I over-ride this CSP so as to replace with what I have set in the meta tag?  From what I can see, the HTTP header is delivering a much more restrictive CSP...?

Comment: Also I have attempted to create a SCRIPT object in my external .js file the page is using.  I still get CSP blocking of that script as well.  I would have thought this would qualify as "script-src 'self'"...however apparently not.  Therefore what exactly is the 'self' directive supposed to be allowing?  I know it does not allow 'inline script' either...if 'inline' and 'external' scripts cannot be processed how am I supposed to resolve this???  I thank you again for your information.

Comment: It's need to know what software do you use on backend. Some of those auto set default CSP header (Helmet 4 for example). The `'self'` token could be a little bit tricky - commonly it means Same Origin Policy (the same Scheme/HostName/PortNumber over which the page was loaded). In CSP3 browsers `'self'` extends `http:` scheme to  `http: https:` and to [ws: wss: too](http://csplite.com/csp/test15/). "I have attempted to create a SCRIPT object" - it's treated as inline script if you creates `<script>...</script>` using `createElement('script')`. Creation of `<script src=...>` is external script.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  I am using Node/Express, and I also use the Helmet module...perhaps this is why my CSP was created through HTTP Headers and is set as it is.  I will remove Helmet and see what effect that has on the CSP.  I believe I can also form the CSP directly within Node.js itself...I will have to research that.

Comment: Yes my external .js file attempts to create the script element using "createElement('SCRIPT').  I wrote that code within the external .js file that is called using a "script src'=/path/to/my/external/js/file"...so I am still confused why it would be considered inline...?  Thanks again for your useful information.

Comment: You can just [switch off CSP](https://helmetjs.github.io/) in Helmet and continue to use other security headers:
`app.use( helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false,}) );`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, much appreciated !