# How to configure Content-Policy-Security header on ExpressJs app?

Tags: node.js, express, header, content-security-policy

I'm want to create a link in my website who download a PDF file but I get a white window with:

```
Cannot GET /file
```

and a Content Security Policy (CSP) error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page settings prevented a resource from loading at inline ("default-src").
```

I use ExpressJs and Nginx for the back-end.

I've tried to set CSP default-src header like this in my app.js file:

```
//Headers setup
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy',"default-src 'self' https://www.mydomain.fr");
    next();
});
```

i've also tried to add this in my .conf file in Nginx:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" always;
```

It is still not working. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

My router:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const fileController = require('../controllers/file');

router.get('/', fileController.getFile);

module.exports = router;
```

My controller:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.getFile = (req, res, next) => {
    res.set({'Content-Type':'application/pdf'});
    res.set({'Content-Disposition':'attachment, filename=file.pdf'});
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/public/documents/file.pdf');
    res.download(filePath, 'file.pdf', (e) => {res.status(404).json({e: e})});
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) or similar? Or any Nginx config relating to it? I don't think Express/Nginx has any CSP rules by default.

Comment: no I just set this header on my app. My nginx conf file don't have any header inside

Comment: `res.setHeader()` is a native NodeJS method, I do not know is it avaliable here. Use `res.set({ "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self';" })` or the alias `res.header({ "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self';" })`. Or use [packages](https://csplite.com/csp211/#CSP_ExpressJS)

Comment: hello, i've tried your code and the code example in csplite.com. None of this works...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your resource is embedded inline (see the csp error).

To allow that use `unsafe-inline`:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy',"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");
    next();
});
```

Comment: Is your script embedded inline?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded inline"? I don't understand. I updated my post by adding router and controller code if it can help you.

Comment: Is the error just on pdf files or on js and css too? Inline: `<style>body{...}</style>`. Not inline: `<script src="..."></script>.

Comment: I made tests and js and css not work too, except on my first page (it's a one-page site).

Answer (score 0):

**SabSab43**, you have been given the correct leads in the comments and answers, but you shouldn't recklessly publish the CSP. You can publish CSP in several ways:

- add_header in Nginx
- HTTP header via res.setHeader()
- specialized Helmet package
- using `<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content="...CSP rules here...">` in the HTML code.

But if you do use all of above at the same time, you'll publish a several different CSPs and as result more restrictive one will acts.

Therefore remove all CSP you added and lets go step by step:

1. Do check the **jonrsharpe**'s remark abt Helmet. The fact is that if you have Helmet 4 connected to Express, it issues the restrictive `default-src 'self'` policy by default.

Therefore after removing all your CSPs, check do you have CSP header in browser, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). If CSP header is presents - some middleware (like Helmet) does publish it. You need to find it and modify the policy in it, or switch it off and use your `res.setHeader(...)`

2. If there is no header (and there is no meta tag either), publish the CSP with any of the methods, and add `'unsafe-inline'` to it, as **kmgt** said. You need to have policy:
   `"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.mydomain.fr"`
   to get rid of *"The page settings prevented a resource from loading at inline ("default-src")"*

Note that *'prevented a resource from loading at inline'* can be about not only inline `<script>`, but about inline `<style>` too. But since you use `default-src', it covers both.

PS: Chrome's console more verbose than Firefox's one. If you fail to fix this issue, pls show the message about the blocking from the Сhrome's console - it will show the rules that block.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted all my CSP Rules (I don't use Helmet or any CSP dependencies) in my app and Nginx .conf file and when I look in browsers developers tools I see again the CSP Rule.

In chrome:
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbRbu.png)

In Firefox:
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSprA.png)

therefore, I've tried to put this code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.set({"Content-Security-Policy":"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.myDomain.fr"});
    next();
});
```

I've the same result than without the CSP Rules...

In Chrome I juste have a 404 error:

> GET https://www.myDomain.fr/file 404 (Not found)

In Firefox

> GET https://www.myDomain.fr/file         [HTTP/1.1 404 Not found 96ms]

> Content Security Policy: The page settings prevented a resource from loading at inline ("default-src").

The 404 is probably caused by the CSP Error...