# Content-Security-Policy for local resources

Tags: content-security-policy

I am trying to deploy a web application in my local using apache tomcat as a container.
I got a simple page with following in head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and when I try to open the page on safari 14 I got error

```
Refused to load http://localhost:8080/webapp/app.js because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I have read documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#examples_common_use_cases) and it looks like 'self' would be enough to load my own resources (for both css and javascript). What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be 2 issues:

1. The `'self'` token does not cover `localhost:8080` (with port number) in Safari. But in this case you should have additionally a 2 CSS blocked, not js only.
   To fix just add `localhost:8080` to the `default-src` directive.
2. Your Apache Tomcat server publish a default CSP via HTTP header. In this case you can't mitigate CSP using the meta tag and have to modify CSP response HTTP header.
   Check do you have a CSP HTTP header published, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

Is this error observed in Safari browser only? What about Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to create a custom Filter to define my own CSP but it looks like it is ignored. Filter is executed but in response I found a completely different CSP. It looks. like apache tomcat is overriding my custom filter.

Comment: You do not need to create custom Filter in Tomcat since you already have CSP published somewhere. Check the framework you do use, may be it publishes default CSP header.