# How to set the Security Policy directive style-src in a file for TYPO3 10

Tags: css, content-security-policy, typo3-10.x

After the upgrade to TYPO3 10 I have discovered a phenomenon. I use the extension fh_debug to generate a simple HTML file which includes a CSS file in the header. This is well shown with the CSS styled content in the browser Firefox or Opera without any problems. However there is a browser warning if it is called under a url of a TYPO3 10 website.

> debug.html:10 Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://localhost/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'none'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

Therefore I have improved the HTML file with meta tags to set the 'style-src'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Debug Devmulti</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://localhost/devmulti/;"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="http://localhost/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>any HTML here.</p>
</body>
```

The browser url is:
`http://localhost/devmulti/fileadmin/debug.html`

If I copy the same file to the TYPO3 9 website, then it works.
`http://localhost/fileadmin/debug.html`

If I copy the same file to a directory on the file system, then it works.
`file:///home/franz/Arbeit/Franz/Debug/debug.html`

What must I change for TYPO3 10?

I have temorarily renamed 2 `.htaccess` files without any success.

`devmulti/fileadmin/.htaccess` and `devmulti/.htaccess` . I did a search these files about **style-src** .

```
[franz@localhost devmulti]$ find . -name '*.*' -type f -exec grep -i 'default-src'  {}  \;  -ls
    protected const HEADER_PATTERN = '#(?<directive>default-src|script-src|style-src|object-src)\h+(?<rule>[^;]+)(?:\s*;\s*|$)#';
        $defaultSrc = isset($this->directives['default-src'])
            ? $this->directiveMitigatesCrossSiteScripting($this->directives['default-src'])
922745      4 -rw-r--r--   1  franz    franz        2539 Feb  5 09:11 ./typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/SystemEnvironment/ServerResponse/ContentSecurityPolicyHeader.php
    content="default-src *; style-src \'self\' ' . $host . ';"/>
1326610     60 -rwxrwxrwx   1  franz    franz       60236 Feb  6 17:30 ./typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Classes/Utility/DebugFunctions.php
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://localhost/devmulti/;"/>
1177376      4 -rw-rw-r--   1  franz    franz         569 Feb  9 09:16 ./fileadmin/debug-stack1.html
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://localhost/devmulti/;"/>
1191268      4 -rwxrwxrwx   1  franz    franz        4054 Feb  6 18:22 ./fileadmin/debug.html
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'none'; object-src 'self'; plugin-types application/pdf;"
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; style-src 'none'; object-src 'none';"
1191266      4 -rw-rw-r--   1  apache   apache       1645 Feb  5 15:45 ./fileadmin/.htaccess
```

Modified `devmulti/fileadmin/.htaccess` at `style-src 'self'`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # matching requested *.pdf files only (strict rules block Safari showing PDF documents)
    <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'none'; object-src 'self'; plugin-types application/pdf;"
    </FilesMatch>
    # matching anything else, using negative lookbehind pattern
    <FilesMatch "(?<!\.pdf)$">
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none';"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This is a standalone HTML file. It does not need TYPO3 to be shown in the browser. It only includes a CSS file in the file sytem.
Here is the used CSS file:  https://github.com/franzholz/fh_debug/blob/master/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css

**1st solution:**
Delete the file `devmulti/fileadmin/.htaccess` and wait for some time. Then the HTML file works with the CSS styled content. Only this message remains.
`Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("default-src").`

Are there better solutions without having to delete a standard `.htaccess` of TYPO3?

Comment: Generally TYPO published CSP via `.htaccess` file therefore you can't relax it in the meta tag. Check do you have a CSP HTTP header published in TYPO3 10, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

Comment: I get this response header: 

`Cache-Control
 max-age=0
Connection
 Keep-Alive
Date
 Mon, 08 Feb 2021 19:46:05 GMT
Expires
 Mon, 08 Feb 2021 19:46:05 GMT
Keep-Alive
 timeout=5, max=100
Server
 Apache/2.4.46 (Mageia) PHP/7.3.23
`
I wonder why TYPO3 should interfere with a HTML file. And it did not help to rename the **.htaccess** files. And I cannot find a CSP inside of them.

Comment: If you do not see CSP in the HTTP header, there is only one opt - it is published in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" `. But you meta tag do not contain `style-src 'none'` rule seen in the console violation message. Check the HTML code for double CSP meta tag. Also some browsers extensions can interfere.

Comment: I ihave modified the HTML code of my example to be complete. You can see it here, that it should work fine. However it has these CSP errors. `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css ("style-src").`

Comment: I get the same CSP errors with Firefox, Opera and Chrome browser on Mageia Linux.
`Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src"). fingerprint-protection.js:343:25
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("default-src"). `

Comment: I have now changed my request, because the fileadmin.htacdess has CSP settings. I do not now why a renaming of the file into orig.htaccess did not change the result. See the enhanced informations above.

Comment: `fingerprint-protection.js:343:25` is unrelated to TYPO3 and probably some ad-blocker (modifying the markup) you've installed in your browser

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 is not involved when `/fileadmin/.htaccess` is invoked, however TYPO3 generated that file in the Install Tool process (see https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/67081). When files from `/fileadmin/` are requested, they are only delivered by the web server (Apache in this case).

In order to allow loading stylesheet files, change directive `style-src 'none'` to `style-src 'self'` and change the `<link href` attribute to be on same-site, e.g. `/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css` (without host prefix).

See https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-psa-2020-003 for a full description, why enforcing CSP for `/fileadmin/` was necessary.

Comment: If I change the `<link href`, then the HTML file is not portable any more. If I open the HTML file on another folder on the file system, then the browser would not find the CSS file any more. Maybe also the CSS file should be written by the extension into fileadmin?

Comment: Just use relative path `<link href="/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public/Css/fhdebug.css"...>` based the web root, not the path within local filesystem. Relative links are very portable, those will work with `http://localhost/...`, `http://localhost:8080/...`, `https://example.com/...` without any modifying of HTML code.

Comment: This is the problem: If I use your proposal `"/devmulti/typo3conf/ext/fh_debug/Resources/Public"` and copy the file debug.html to my local computer in a folder /home/franz/example, then I must generate the same hierarchy of subfolders at this position and also copy the file `fhdebug.css` there. So  `debug.html`  is not easily portable any more.