# Patternlab: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, browser-sync, patternlab.io, unsafe-inline

I am the only frontend guy who gets the error when running Patternlab, while other devs seem to start it normally, I get the next error message (cross-browser)

[image]

I cannot seem to fix it no matter what I try, set up the project new, set up a new instance of Patternlab, delete and reinstall node, and so on. Does someone have a clue what could be the issue and how to fix it?

I use a Macbook Pro (Idk if my OS or overall some aspects of my machine have any influence on this)

Comment: Looks like Content Security Policy header is published by the backend. For example NodeJS with Helmet 4 publishes its own default Content Security Policy. Check the concole do you have CSP HTTP header, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

Comment: @granty I managed to fix it to some degree, the issue with CSP but rn I have encountered another issue, which is that after starting my pattern lab instance I only get the listing directory

Comment: CSP must be fixed to no any errors in the console. Anyway you can disable CSP header to check is it affect you lab instance or not.

Comment: @granty Thanks for the tip, anyways found the answer, someone installed some patches on certain packaged in the node modules and it messed up my setup after I tried installing the package.json packages as there were missmatched React versions, so yeah the solution was to install these 2 packages separately which were affected by the patch and then installation ran smoothly