# Content-Security-Policy will not load images from external sources in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, content-security-policy

I am having an issue with setting the Content Security Policy (CSP) for a React app. I am setting it with a meta tag in the head element of the index.html file.

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="img-src 'self' https://via.placeholder.com/ data:"
    />
```

I want to load images from an external source and I have added the source origin to the meta tag but I have not been able to get the images to load in the application. I have tried a large number of variations for the format of the CSP, but I still have not been able to get the images to load. I am using a production build of the app that has been created with create-react-app and is being served by a Node server. Furthermore, I have set  INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false in a .env file to make sure that no inline JavaScript is generated in the index.html file.
The following error is generated when the application attempts to load the image.

```
Refused to load the image 'https://via.placeholder.com/150' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

It is my understanding that setting the img-src directive to the domain, in this case https://via.placeholder.com/, should allow loading of images from that domain. A * (wildcard) or https://* should allow images from all external domains or https-only domains, to be loaded into the application. However, it continues to show the same error message no matter what I put into the img-src directive. Additionally, I have added the ‘data:’ attribute with and without the wildcard (i.e. data:*) and have received the same error message. I have also tried to change the default-src directive to include the wildcard for all sources, as shown in the following code.

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:*"
    />
```

But, the error message will still not go away. I am fundamentally misunderstanding CSP? Or is there something else that I need to add in order to load images from external sources?

Answer (score 2):

The message *`...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:"`* means you actually have CSP `img-src 'self' data:`, not `img-src 'self' https://via.placeholder.com/ data:`.

The

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:*"
/>
```

does not work because you have second (more rectrictive) CSP via  or HTTP header. I think this second CSP is issued by `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` of [Helmet middleware](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference). In case of 2 CSPs are allowed only sources that passes unscratched via both CSP at the same time.

Check the HTML code for presence of second `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...>` tag.
And check in the Dev Tool do you delivery CSP with the HTTP header, [here is tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

BTW, `data:*` is a wrong syntax for non-network schemes. Use just sheme-sources like `data:`, `blob:`, `filesystem:`. For network schemes you can use both `https://*` or `https:`, but those are a little bit different in action because the first one is a `<host-source>`, the second - `<scheme-source>`.

Comment: I removed the Helmet middleware from the Node server's middleware pipeline and it did indeed stop the errors generated by Helmet's second CSP policy.