# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at domain.com (“default-src”)

Tags: php, content-security-policy

I'm trying to embed a twitch.tv player in my webpage but I keep getting:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=bluebeast8888&parent=http://blue.requiem.moe (“default-src”).
```

My current header settings:

```
    header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.twitch.tv; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; frame-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.twitch.tv;");
```

My current meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' player.twitch.tv; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.twitch.tv">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It can be 2 issues:

A). You use non CSP3-compatible browser. On HTTP: pages the schemeless sources will obtain schemes via Same Origin Policy. Therefore `player.twitch.tv` -> `http://player.twitch.tv` and `*.twitch.tv` -> `http://*.twitch.tv`.
Both `http://*.twitch.tv` and `http://player.twitch.tv` do not allow iframe with `httpS://player.twitch.tv` in CSP2 browsers (while CSP3 browsers allow upgrade http: to https:).
In this case use source with scheme like `default-src 'self' https://player.twitch.tv` if you embed `<iframe src='https://player.twitch.tv'>` with exact scheme.

B). Probably your CSP header is overridden by other CSP in `.htaccess` or web server config. HTTP header you shown contains `frame-src`, but you observe violation in the `default-src`, it means that not HTTP header is the reason of lock.
Check what CSP header is really delivered to a web page, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) is tutorial.
Alternatively you can have a look into Chrome browser console - it's more verbose than Firefoxes one, and will show not only violated directive, but its riles too.

**BTW**

1. You have an error in Url p`https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=bluebeast8888&parent=http://blue.requiem.moe` (have a look into Dev Tools or browser console), the `parent=http://blue.requiem.moe` parameter should be without `http://` scheme:

`https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=bluebeast8888&parent=http://blue.requiem.moe`

2. You have [different](https://csplite.com/csp/cmp/?pl=eJyVj90KgkAUhO8F30H2RhAU%2FIlgvewFgp5gW8%2FSxnGV3dWQ6N3TtYJSou7mDOdjZhjN6dXQDSUIPSApJc1KM5pkd9iTUWVpQUkFgnVoY6N5EBpAEQZRYi%2FS8lNi%2B9L3fE9oVsP80CnDBMTQMwxfl1QoFSy5GirJHBe5uzmegT%2BSVDMSzjVcy%2FYt%2F2vKzNgBYQ15Pk3zCjc0m2Sab1eXtsgG0B%2B1%2Fyy0mP1DudsdoueCfw%3D%3D) CSPs in HTTP header and meta tag.

Multiple policies operates by logical "AND" - all sources should pass unscrathed trough both CSP.
Keep 2 CSPs at the same is a headache, remove one ot that.

3. The `frame-src` directive does not support `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` tokens, you can remove them.