# Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/'

Tags: paypal, content-security-policy

I'm trying to setup a paypal transparent checkout but got stuck on the CSP brower error, i did all the tests in sandbox mode and it worked like a charm, but when i turned it to live env, i started receiving CSP errors, i tried all kinds of values on `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="XXXXXXXXXX">` and it still didn't work, how can i solve it?

full browser console error:

> payment-selection:1 Refused to set the document's base URI to
> 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/c30/165e8147117bd1483979affdece85'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com".

Comment: Just add blocked source into `base-uri` directive: `"base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://www.paypalobjects.com"`. The `https://www.paypalobjects.com` domain is under PayPal control, since `Nslookup paypalobjects.com` resolve into IP 64.4.250.19, 64.4.250.20, 64.4.250.14 and all `64.4.240.0 - 64.4.251.255` range belongs to PayPal. Therefore it's not a malware is blocked by CSP, but some PayPal stuff.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, it returned the same error, i tried like this:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://www.paypalobjects.com">

Comment: i'm on localhost, does it matter?

Comment: Looks like by `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com paypalobjects.com">` you published a second CSP. You have to edit the first one, may be it's published via HTTP header.

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't understand, how you mean second CSP and edit the first one? this is the only one i'm using

Comment: If you have only one CSP then error should be `... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://paypalobjects.com"' (https://paypalobjects.com should appear) . But you say you have the same error as before. This means that is applied the same CSP as before, but not from meta tag you show.

Comment: i'm confused haha, i used the one you commented above (only one), this:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://www.paypalobjects.com">

the error is:

Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/c30/165e8147117bd1483979affdece85' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com".

Comment: the print screen of the current html code and the error shown on the console:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/hhdgr5r

Comment: Ok, before you added the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com paypalobjects.com">`, you have CSP been published somewhere - exactly this CSP blocked `base-uri` access with the message in the startpost. Need to change the base-uri directive in this original CSP, instead of add meta tag.

Comment: i think i understand now, but i don't have any CSP prior to this one, i also tried to define this exactly CSP header on apache htaccess and it also didn't work

Comment: If you didn't have any CSP, who blocked `https://www.paypalobjects.com/` in the startpost? Could you please check do you have any CSP in the HTTP header, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). It does not matter how to publish CSP: via meta tag or via htaccess file. Note: if CSP does not have `base-uri` directive, the lock as in startpost will never occurs.

Comment: Is this your CSP fault or not? The browser console is one and all errors fall into one heap. For example, if you are using Paypal `<iframe>`, it publishes its CSP, and an error may occur in it. You cannot fix the error of someone else's CSP.

Comment: well, i honestly have no idea, because i forced my CSP headers also on my backend (PHP, and/or Apache) and also tested only with meta-tags, i seen that alot of people are suffering from this issue on paypal forums, but i thought it was my application's problem

Comment: You can temporary remove your own CSP and check if it's a Paypal's `<iframe>` problem or not. You can not influ to CSP published in the foreign iframe.

Comment: that's the problem, i'm using the checkout only with js, but it seems that the form "injected" by Paypal javascript uses iframe underneath

Comment: Yes, Paypal payment it's always iframe. I should have guessed right away that base-uri + Paypal domain - haven't be relevant to your page. It's a Paypal's CSP internal trouble. I hope this error does not block payment on the site, because only Paypal can fix it.

Comment: I have a same issue with paypal+. Since morning, reading different forums and many people are suffering from this but there is no solution ^^