# Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive ''self''

Tags: content-security-policy

I have an error please let me know how to solve it

[ Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive ''self''. ]

[ The Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains 'style-src' as a source expression. Did you mean 'default-src ...; style-src...' (note the semicolon)? ]

The code used is

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src style-src 'unsafe-inline'; 'self';"
```

Comment: Use a semicolons as is exampled in the console message, Directives seperate by semicolon, so you have to use `default-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';`

Comment: The problem still exists

Comment: Check what CSP your browser get from server, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). Maybe you forgot restart Apache after config edit or edit wrong config.