# Stripe Connect : Content Security Policy issue

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

Even By using meta tags, It is still showing error and Iframe is not working

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
         default-src *; 
         style-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline'; 
         script-src * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com 'unsafe-inline' 
         connect-src : * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com  'unsafe-inline' 
         frame-src : * 'self'  https://checkout.stripe.com  'unsafe-inline' 
         'unsafe-eval' 
         ;" >
```

Link reference : https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Error : Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

Also I used header() to set this up, but that also didn't worked.  Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Your CSP has a lot of errors:

1. You have missed semicolons `;` to separate `script-src` / `connect-src` / `frame-src` directives lists.
2. `:` is nor required in the `connect-src : * ...` and in the `frame-src : * ...`
3. Remove `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` from the `connect-src` and `frame-src` directives, those are not supported there
4. The `*` (asterisk) [covers](https://csplite.com/csp/test283/) any host-sources like `https://checkout.stripe.com` and `wss://checkout.stripe.com`

BUT these are not significant, these just leads the CSP you have really is:

```
default-src *; 
style-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
```

This CSP restrict nothing except `data:`-Urls usage. Therefore the error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)
```

cannot belong your CSP.
Looks like you already have CSP header published somewhere. Hence second CSP via `<meta>` or HTTP header does not have effect as expected.

Check what CSP header you really have got in browser, the tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

Check web-server config in Nginx for `add_header Content-Security-Policy ...` or `.htaccess` file (if Apache) for `Header set Content-Security-Policy ...` presence.
Or maybe you have installed some plugins for managing CSP headers.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `img-src https://*.stripe.com` described in the Stripe documentation.

Also the asterisk character alone doesn't work as "any resource" (example of incorrect use in your code: `default-src *`). You need to use it as part of the `<host-source>` (e.g. `*.example.com`). See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) for more details.