# Website stuck in loading or disables functionality when inactive for a period

Tags: python-3.x, content-security-policy

If the user has no activity(mouse, keyboard) in some period of time, API'S not working, I inspected and went to the network tab and found CSP is blocking.

[image: Tried by adding meta link, but it's not working.]

**Attempt:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src 'self';script-src 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' 'my-urls' ;">
```

Tried by adding meta link, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you observe CSP blocking, you already have a CSP published in the page. You can't relax this CSP by publishing a second CSP in meta tag, you need to edit a first one.
   You can check what CSP your already have in browser, a tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).
2. XHR requests are covered by `connect-src` directive, therefore you have to add `connect-src 'self'` or `connect-src https://your_domain.com` if you perform connect to a site's own domain.
   But first check a "Console tab" - it should be a CSP violation message like:

   `Refused to connect to wss://example.com/ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive ...`

   `Refused to connect to https://example.com/ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive ...`

You need to verify that `wss://example.com/` or `https://example.com/` is your legitimate domain, because this can be antics of some browser plugin or third-party iframe on page.
After thar you can add `wss://example.com/` or `https://example.com/` (depending what is blocked) into `connect-src` directive.