# CSP, RocketLoader and Nginx?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, content-security-policy, rocket-loader

So I'm trying to avoid using (another) page rule to disable Rocketloader for one of my subdomains, since we can't use a RegEx to select multiple specific subdomains under a single page rule, and only get 3 page rules for free accounts.

According to this page:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/216537517-Using-Content-Security-Policy-CSP-with-Cloudflare

I can just add a header to the domain to allow scripts from CloudFlare:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ajax.cloudflare.com;";
```

I did so in the Nginx config for that subdomain (it's a Chronograph container actually), restarted Nginx, tested to make sure it "took", which it did:

[image: image|690x320]

But then when I try to load the domain, it won't load, and the inspector shows this:

[image: image|690x50]

Not being super familiar with this, does anyone know where I screwed it up?

Comment: I've already tried purging the CloudFlare cache and browser cache and trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where I screwed it up?

First of all, here:

> I can just **add a header** to the domain to allow scripts from CloudFlare:
>     `add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ajax.cloudflare.com;";`
> I **did so** in the Nginx config

And secondly, you trusted the `report-uri` service, but it failed you.

1. You have had an issue with `ajax.cloudflare.com` BEFORE adding CSP header into Nginx config (otherwise, why add it). This means that you already have a CSP published via an HTTP header or a meta tag `<meta http-equiv= 'Content-Security-Policy'>`.
     By adding the CSP header to the Nginx configuration, you have added a **second** policy to the pages.
     Multiple CSPs work as sequential filters - all sources must pass through both CSPs to be resolved. The second CSP allows `ajax.cloudflare.com` host-source, but the first one still prohibits it (that you are observe in the inspector).

You have to figure out where the first CSP is published and to add `ajax.cloudflare.com` into it, instead of publish second CSP.

2. No one know what is under the hood of the `report-uri` and how it will react if two CSP HTTP  headers or an HTTP header paired with a meta tag are published simultaneously
     Have a look which CSP and how many of them the browser actually gets, the guide is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).
     In case of 2 CSP headers you will see something like that:
   [image]

In case of CSP meta tag you can easily check the by inspecting the HTML code.

I think the `report-uri` just did not expect such a situation.

Comment: You da man, that's what the issue was; double headers declaring the CSP. Not having much experience in this area I would've just assumed adding it to the Nginx config it would overwrite the previous one if it existed. In my specific case since I'm using a container for the site and don't have much control over the source, in my Nginx conf for the site I first had to remove the existing one with `proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;` and then immediately under that, add it how I need it: `add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ajax.cloudflare.com;";`

Comment: You are right, in ordinary cases it should overrides previous header with the same name. Maybe a Chronograph container make a some mess with that.