# CSP, Refused to load the script, violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meta-tags, mapbox-gl-js, content-security-policy

Can someone explain me how can i add CSP meta tag to my header?
i tried adding different meta tag to my header but i get more error from CSP

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:*//api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js;">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:gap 'unsafe-eval' ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' script-src *; media-src *; font-src *;  connect-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

[console error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwk3C.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have a published CSP via an HTTP header because a console error saying:

*it violates the following Content Security Policy directive "**default-src 'self'**"*

while your meta tag contains other `default-src` sources: **default-src 'self' https:*//api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js**

You can check the CSP response HTTP header that you have, the tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).

In this case by adding meta tag you'll have 2 CSPs which will work independently each other, therefore CSP in HTTP header will continue to block your scripts.

Node.js has a Helmet middleware in dependancies, [Helmet 4](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet#user-content-how-it-works) automatically publishes a default CSP via HTTP header. Check it.
In this case you have 2 opts:

- disable Helmet's CSP: `app.use( helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false, }) );` and use a meta tag.
- configure CSP header via Helmet (preferred way).

> 

BTW you have errors in the:

```
default-src 'self' data:gap 'unsafe-eval' ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' script-src *; media-src *; font-src *;  connect-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;
```

1. `data:gap` is a wrong source, use `data:` or `data: gap:` depending on what you need.
2. missed `;` before `script-src`