# How to fix refused to load the script https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: google-maps-api-3, content-security-policy

I got a issue and can not using
use-places-autocomplete, I have try to fix it but still not resolve it
In env local, I load script google map not get any issue, but env production I got the following error.

Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=weekly&key=xxxxxyyyyyyddđd&libraries=places&language=vi' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com) connect.facebook.net [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com) [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) googleads.g.doubleclick.net onesignal.com tpc.googlesyndication.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

This is how I try, but still can not fix it:

```
<meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' developers.google.com maps.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://connect.facebook.net https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://onesignal.com https://tpc.googlesyndication.com;" />
```

And don't know where the other sources are called from, because I don't use it like: [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com), connect.facebook.net, [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com), [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com), googleads.g.doubleclick .net,...

Looking forward to all the helpers. Thanks all.

Source:

NextJS: 11.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You are on a right way (I mean an adding `maps.googleapis.com` into `script-src`), but looks like you already published CSP via HTTP header, therefore your `<meta>` tag is not working.

Check if you already have a CSP header, a manual is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629).
If you already have a CSP header, you need to make corrections to it, and not publish the second CSP in the meta tag.

It is very likely that your CSP header is published by [Helmet middleware](https://helmetjs.github.io/), it's in NodeJS dependencies.