# ContentSecurityPolicy Preventing fetch request in Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, fetch, content-security-policy

I am trying to build an electron application which makes api requests, but when I make an api call, I get the following errors:

> Refused to connect to '<API_URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

> Refused to connect to '<API_URL>' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

The code I am using to make the request is

```
const getContent = async (url) => await fetch(url)
```

I tried adding a meta tag to allow unsafe-eval and setting webSecurity to false in the BrowserWindow and neither appeared to have any effect. I also tried making the request with axios and got the same response. I haven't been able to find any other instances of this issue on the internet despite seeing several examples of people making api requests from inside of Electron.

Comment: Since you had a CSP issue before adding `<meta>`, you already have a some CSP published via meta tag or HTTP header ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) is a manual how to check this). Therefore adding `<meta CSP>` will not help, it just add a second CSP while the first one still continue blocking. You have to find where the first CSP is published and add domain from the blocked Url into it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you use electron-forge, this resource will be helpful. https://githubmemory.com/repo/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/2331

Go to package.json, look for config and then plugin and insert this

```
"devContentSecurityPolicy":"default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;"
```

Incase you are still confused, this is my package.json code

```
 {
  "name": "x",
  "productName": "x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "x"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "devContentSecurityPolicy":"default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;",
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./public/index.html",
                  "js": "./public/renderer.js",
                  "name": "main_window"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "1.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "^15.3.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "npm": "^7.22.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.10.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker": "^3.2.0",
    "@y0c/react-datepicker": "^1.0.4",
    "aes-js": "^3.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^25.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "electron-splashscreen": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "hex64": "^0.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lottie-react": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "node-jsencrypt": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^7.0.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.4.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dropdown-input": "^0.1.11",
    "react-geolocated": "^3.2.0",
    "react-live-clock": "^5.2.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.3.1",
    "react-qr-code": "^2.0.2",
    "react-responsive": "^8.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.13.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.5",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "rsuite": "^4.10.2",
    "systeminformation": "^5.8.7",
    "text-to-binary-converter": "^1.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "zustand": "^3.5.7"
  }
}
```