# Electronjs with axios no response

Tags: javascript, axios, electron, content-security-policy

I just started learning electronjs.  I have added `axios` in my `preload.js` file

```
const axios = require('axios'); 

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
.then(function (response) {
  // handle success
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
  // always executed
});
```

I do get a `status:200` as a response, but there is no response data.  there are also no console messages.  Am i missing something?  But if I do the request after the content load, it returns an error.

```
const axios = require('axios'); 

let getData = () => {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  getData();
});
```

the above returns `Refused to connect to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ContentSecurityPolicy Preventing fetch request in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790650/contentsecuritypolicy-preventing-fetch-request-in-electron)

Comment: When you say there is no response data, is the `data` property of the response object undefined? https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: @Phil Thanks, i will will take a look at it.

Comment: @NickBailey Thank you for commenting.  as i have said also above.. there are no console messages.  looking at the `network` tab.. the `preview` is blank

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with loading image from external URL to my background.
In my `index.ts` (entry point of electron app) I subscribe to `"ready"` event and specify this `responseHeaders`. `*` means that we can accept all resources that need to be load for current page. It's not recommended to use `*` flag, but just for testing I use it. More: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

```
import { session, app } from "electron"

app.on("ready", () => {
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        "Content-Security-Policy": ["*"],
      },
    });
  });
})
```