# Content security policy - different behaviour windows vs linux

Tags: apache, browser, content-security-policy

I have a wordpress website that runs on a LAMP system.

I tried to improve security (I'm far from being an expert!) and added a CSP header.

```
Header  set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src https://www.google.com https://www.youtube.com; img-src 'self' https://secure.gravatar.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'none'"
```

What I don't understand: If I remove the `unsafe-inline` from the `script-src` my calendar widget does not load anymore on a windows browser (tested both firefox and chrome). But it works on a Linux browser (Firefox).

Is this a bug in apache2, in the windows browsers or in the calender wp plugin?

I'm confused. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like an Apache bug, it just sends the CSP as a string without even understanding what's in it.

Of course you can use some User Agent conditions in the `httpd.conf` like:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Linux x86_64" noCSP=1
```

and to publish CSP relying on `noCSP` flag to exclude CSP header for some kinds od user agents.
But you can [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) clarify that and ensure you have the same CSP header for the Windows/Linux browsers.

> 

I think a WP calendar plugin uses some inline scripts which are blocked in absence of `'unsafe-inline'`. You can check accourding CSP errors in the browser console of windows browser.

Maybe you disabled CSP in your Linux Firefox browser (`about:config` page ->  `security.csp.enable` -> false) or have some extensions which disable CSP.

Comment: CSP is enabled in the Linux Firefox. I'm running very few extensions - the only one in the CSP regime is Laboratory but that is for creating a header for a website and does hopefully not influence Firefox behaviour (correction: it does - just found out that when recording a website csp is disabled - solution!)
I have asked the plugin author whether he can clarify about the ```unsafe-inline``` in his plugin, but no answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

So the different Windows/Linux behaviour  comes from the Laboratory plugin that was running in my Linux Firefox.
I have to check with the plugin author why `unsafe-inline` is required.