# Electron Content Security Policy error when connecting to my api

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, electron, content-security-policy

Creating a simple template electron app. I want to do a fetch request to my api but am continuously stopped by the Content Security Policy errors and I have no idea how to fix them.

> Refused to connect to 'https://api.myapp.com/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly
> set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
 const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.myapp.com/books", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    return response.json();
  };
```

I have tried adding the api address to the existing policy, and adding additional policies but nothing works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer to this. It seems that Webpack uses a default Content Security Policy for developer mode which can be overridden in the package.json.

Taken from webpack WebpackPluginRendererConfig

```
/**
     * Sets the [`Content-Security-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)
     * for the Webpack development server.
     *
     * Normally you would want to only specify this as a `<meta>` tag. However, in development mode,
     * the Webpack plugin uses the `devtool: eval-source-map` source map setting for efficiency
     * purposes. This requires the `'unsafe-eval'` source for the `script-src` directive that wouldn't
     * normally be recommended to use. If this value is set, make sure that you keep this
     * directive-source pair intact if you want to use source maps.
     *
     * Default: `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;`
     * `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:`
     */
    devContentSecurityPolicy?: string;
```

By setting devContentSecurityPolicy in package.json I can set my own Content Security Policy.

```
"plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "devContentSecurityPolicy": "connect-src 'self' https://api.myapp.com 'unsafe-eval'",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
                  "name": "main_window"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
```

*Note: Changing this and saving wont update the policy in the app. You need to stop and run 'npm start' again to apply these changes.*

Comment: to get my electron app talking to my localhost server I did:
`"devContentSecurityPolicy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:* ws://localhost:*;",`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using forge.config.ts you can use:

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackPlugin({
      mainConfig,
      devContentSecurityPolicy: "connect-src 'self' * 'unsafe-eval'",
      renderer: {
        config: rendererConfig,
        entryPoints: [
          {
            html: './src/index.html',
            js: './src/index.tsx',
            name: 'main_window',
            preload: {
              js: './src/preload.ts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 6):

In the violation message you have a whitelist: *Refused to connect to ... the following Content Security Policy directive: "**default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:"**.*

But in the meta tag you shown a different whitelist: ***default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'***.

This means you have at least 2 CSPs in action. Several CSPs act as consistent filters - all sources intended to be allowed should pass all filters. As result a toughest rules from all CSP are applied.

Figure out where do you publish a first CSP and add `connect-src https://api.myapp.com` into it. And remove CSP in the meta tag.

Most likely it's some package publishes his default CSP via HTTP header ([how to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629)), so the [Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) is under suspicion - it publishes  default CSP since v4.
Of course you can publish CSP HTTP header directly with code like:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
  callback({ responseHeaders: Object.assign({
    ...details.responseHeaders,
    "Content-Security-Policy": [ "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:" ]
    }, details.responseHeaders)});
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this response, it helped me track down the additional content security policy.

Answer (score 2):

Here in my case, HTML Meta was

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe inline'" />
```

The Error that I was getting in my console

`Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/categories' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

So, as in error it is clearly mentioned that `"default-src 'self'"`. That means by default source for everything will be self. It is also mentioned that I need to set `"connect-src"`,

My Solution to this, just append this to your Content-Security-Policy Meta tag `"connect-src http://localhost:* ws://localhost:*"` you can set any url you need or even multiple url. Like: `connect-src http://127.0.0.1:* ws://localhost:* https://myapiurl.dev`

Here `ws://localhost:*` is needed for your code HMR you can replace * with your dev server port also.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe inline'; connect-src http://localhost:* ws://localhost:* " />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the following line from your `html` code snippet:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ">
```

Comment: You will need to explain why this line was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `helmet()` function for improving security in node js application then just edit the helmet middlewares with seting the directives of what external library you can use in this case as a script i set the self script and other scrips depending on the external libraries that was used:

```
app.use(
  app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://unpkg.com'],
      connectSrc: ["'self'", 'https://reqres.in']
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove this part

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ">
```

and what's related to that