# Chrome ignoring CSP (Content Security Policy) affecting Browser Link on ASP.NET application using .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, content-security-policy, browser-link

I am trying to get the browser link to work on a .net core asp.net application. Although I am setting the CSP properly (at least I think I am), Chrome seems to be using a default. Here is what I see in the console:

[image: console errors]

This is what I have in the shared layout used by all views:

[image: code defining CSP]

This is the source rendered on the browser (Chrome) when pressing Ctrl+U:

[image: this the CSP meta tag in the head tag]

The part that is confusing is that the error messages in the console are saying that the default-src is set to 'self' which is clearly not the case; I am specifying **default-src https://localhost:*;**

Am I missing something here or is this a google Chrome issue? Maybe is a setting I am not aware of, but I've scoured the web and have not found a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The part that is confusing is that the error messages in the console are saying that the default-src is set to 'self' which is clearly not the case; I am specifying **default-src https://localhost:*;**

That's because your asp.net app publishes CSP via HTTP header (you can [see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629)).

So you have 2 CSPs delivered: one via meta tag and second - via HTTP header. In this case both are applied consequentially and a strictest one does block.

Check `web.config` file for lines like:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'" />
<content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
```

Also check the [NWebsec NuGet](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Configuring-csp.html) package settings - it can publish CSP header via `web.config` file, via middleware or via MVC attributes:

- NWebsec.AspNetCore.Mvc package provides configure CSP via MVC attributes.
- NWebsec.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers package includes Tag helpers to manage the script and style 'nonces'.
- NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware package includes OWIN CSP middleware.

You have to use meta tag or HTTP header to publish Content Security Policy, but not both at the same time.